# What is the largest integer range from 0 to N-1 that can be represented by an IEEE 754 double-precision floating point value in the range [0, 1)?

Tags: floating-point, ieee-754

If we map the double-precision floating-point range `[0, 1)` to the integer range `[0-N)` by multiplying the floating-point range by the integer value `N` then what is the largest number `N` such that all numbers `[0-N)` are represented when truncating/flooring the result of `float_value * N` to an integer? No extended precision multiplication. N is rounded to a representable value.

Comment: @EricPostpischil does the multiplication operation guarantee us that any double-precision float in [0, 1) when multiplied by 2^53+1 can actually compute all the integers in the range [0, 2^53], or will there be holes?

Comment: No extended precision multiplication. N rounded to a representable value.

Comment: @UltimateHawk Better to add constraints like [No extended precision multiplication. N rounded to a (double-precision) representable value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76464038/what-is-the-largest-integer-range-from-0-to-n-1-that-can-be-represented-by-an-ie#comment134827681_76464038) to the question.

Comment: 2^53 obviously works. And if N is larger than 2^53, then N ⩾ 2^53 + 1, and 2^53 + 1 ∈ [0,N] is not exactly representable. So any N > 2^53 will fail. That's much simpler than Eric's answer. Or by [0,N], do you mean "all floating-point numbers of [0,N] that are also integers" (thus excluding integers that are not exactly representable)?

Answer (score 1):

First, consider *N* = 2<sup>53</sup>. For every integer *k* ∊ [0, 2<sup>53</sup>), *k*/2<sup>53</sup> is representable in IEEE-754 double precision (binary64) as +*k*•2<sup>−53</sup>, since each number representable in binary64 may be described as a sign and a 53-bit integer multiplied by a power of 2, 2<sup>*e*</sup>, for an integer power *e* ∊ [−1074, +972). Each such *k*/2<sup>53</sup> is in [0, 1), and the floating-point multiplication of each such *k*/2<sup>53</sup> by *N* (2<sup>53</sup>) incurs no rounding error, producing exactly *k*. Therefore, each integer in [0, *N*) is mapped to by at least one binary64 number in [0, 1).

*N* cannot be 2<sup>53</sup>+1 since it is not representable (it requires 54 bits to represent, and the binary64 significand has only 53 bits). For larger *N*, the integer 2<sup>53</sup>+1 is in [0, *N*) but cannot be the result of any binary64 multiplication because it is not representable.

Therefore 2<sup>53</sup> is the largest value for *N* that satisfies the constraints of the question.

Comment: This is much more complex than necessary (if I correctly understand the question). For the second part, just notice that if N > 2^53, then 2^53 + 1 ∈ [0,N], and this number cannot be represented exactly, thus cannot be the result of the multiplication. So this excludes any N > 2^53.

Comment: Could you go into more detail about how "...incurs no rounding error, producing exactly k." How can this be known?

Comment: @UltimateHawk: Floating-point arithmetic only rounds the mathematical result if it is not representable int he floating point format. When *k* is an integer in [0, 2^53), the product of *k* / 2^53 and 2^53 is always representable, since it is *k*, which fits in a 53-bit signfiicand. So there is no rounding.